# php output of generated custom metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox

I have used WordPress Meta Box Generator v2 Beta website to generate a custom meta box to upload a custom image file in to custom post and in admin side everything seems to work fine but I can not to figure out how to make an output on front-end.
So I have tried different variation of `<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'project_logo_logo-image', true ); ?>` but nothing seems to work and make any output at all.
Could you point me in right direction please?

[image: WordPress Meta Box Generator v2 Beta meta box settings]

```
    class Rational_Meta_Box {
    private $screens = array(
        'portfolio_post_type',
    );
    private $fields = array(
        array(
            'id' => 'logo-image',
            'label' => 'Logo Image',
            'type' => 'media',
        ),
    );

    /**
     * Class construct method. Adds actions to their respective WordPress hooks.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'add_meta_boxes' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_footer', array( $this, 'admin_footer' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' add_meta_boxes function.
     * Goes through screens (post types) and adds the meta box.
     */
    public function add_meta_boxes() {
        foreach ( $this->screens as $screen ) {
            add_meta_box(
                'project-logo',
                __( 'Project Logo', 'yopta' ),
                array( $this, 'add_meta_box_callback' ),
                $screen,
                'normal',
                'default'
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Generates the HTML for the meta box
     * 
     * @param object $post WordPress post object
     */
    public function add_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
        wp_nonce_field( 'project_logo_data', 'project_logo_nonce' );
        echo 'Add Project Logo Image';
        $this->generate_fields( $post );
    }

    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' admin_footer function.
     * Adds scripts for media uploader.
     */
    public function admin_footer() {
        ?><script>
            // https://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/
            jQuery(document).ready(function($){
                if ( typeof wp.media !== 'undefined' ) {
                    var _custom_media = true,
                    _orig_send_attachment = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
                    $('.rational-metabox-media').click(function(e) {
                        var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
                        var button = $(this);
                        var id = button.attr('id').replace('_button', '');
                        _custom_media = true;
                            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment){
                            if ( _custom_media ) {
                                $("#"+id).val(attachment.url);
                            } else {
                                return _orig_send_attachment.apply( this, [props, attachment] );
                            };
                        }
                        wp.media.editor.open(button);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $('.add_media').on('click', function(){
                        _custom_media = false;
                    });
                }
            });
        </script><?php
    }

    /**
     * Generates the field's HTML for the meta box.
     */
    public function generate_fields( $post ) {
        $output = '';
        foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
            $label = '<label for="' . $field['id'] . '">' . $field['label'] . '</label>';
            $db_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'project_logo_' . $field['id'], true );
            switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                case 'media':
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input class="regular-text" id="%s" name="%s" type="text" value="%s"> <input class="button rational-metabox-media" id="%s_button" name="%s_button" type="button" value="Upload" />',
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id'],
                        $db_value,
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id']
                    );
                    break;
                default:
                    $input = sprintf(
                        '<input %s id="%s" name="%s" type="%s" value="%s">',
                        $field['type'] !== 'color' ? 'class="regular-text"' : '',
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['id'],
                        $field['type'],
                        $db_value
                    );
            }
            $output .= $this->row_format( $label, $input );
        }
        echo '<table class="form-table"><tbody>' . $output . '</tbody></table>';
    }

    /**
     * Generates the HTML for table rows.
     */
    public function row_format( $label, $input ) {
        return sprintf(
            '<tr><th scope="row">%s</th><td>%s</td></tr>',
            $label,
            $input
        );
    }
    /**
     * Hooks into WordPress' save_post function
     */
    public function save_post( $post_id ) {
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['project_logo_nonce'] ) )
            return $post_id;

        $nonce = $_POST['project_logo_nonce'];
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $nonce, 'project_logo_data' ) )
            return $post_id;

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
            return $post_id;

        foreach ( $this->fields as $field ) {
            if ( isset( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] ) ) {
                switch ( $field['type'] ) {
                    case 'email':
                        $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_email( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        $_POST[ $field['id'] ] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
                        break;
                }
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_logo_' . $field['id'], $_POST[ $field['id'] ] );
            } else if ( $field['type'] === 'checkbox' ) {
                update_post_meta( $post_id, 'project_logo_' . $field['id'], '0' );
            }
        }
    }
}
new Rational_Meta_Box;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested your shared code on my site and it is working fine for me displaying path of saved image using following code as shown in the attached screenshots.

```
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'project_logo_logo-image', true );
```

Please make sure you have added the above code in the file where the post id is accessible.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am lost. Guess something wrong with post query then but it displays other bits without any problem.`<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio_post_type', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  the_title();
  echo '<div class="entry-content">';
  the_content();
  echo '</div>';
                ?>
                <div class="entry-logo">
                    <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'project_logo_logo-image', true ); ?>`